# xtabs and dplyr yielding slightly different proportions

Tags: r, dplyr, mismatch

I'm trying to get average proportions of a binary response across participants and conditions. An `xtabs` returns this:

```
prop.table(xtabs(~condition + newHigh, data),1)

              newHigh
condition     high      low
pauseN2       0.1000000 0.9000000
duration      0.1833333 0.8166667
fallingInt    0.2166667 0.7833333
pause         0.6333333 0.3666667
pauseDuration 0.5666667 0.4333333
pauseRising   0.5833333 0.4166667
risingInt     0.4833333 0.5166667
```

Because I wanted to plot the overall mean % of high but also add the SE of all participants (n=10), I used `dplyr`:

```
prop = data %>%
       group_by(participant, condition, newHigh) %>%
       summarise(n = n()) %>%
       mutate(Freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
       filter(newHigh == "high")
```

I manually checked the counts and proportions for a couple of participants in `prop`, and they are correct (they match my `xtabs`). However, the overall means are slightly off across all conditions when I plot it using `stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se)` in `ggplot`.

I suspect there's something wrong with my `mutate` line above. Has anyone experience this type of mismatch before?

## Data sample

```
     participant     condition newHigh
327      BP03_vA    fallingInt     low
502      BP05_vA   pauseRising     low
835      BP08_vB      duration    high
90       BP01_vA      duration     low
1040     BP10_vA      duration     low
961      BP09_vB    fallingInt     low
518      BP05_vA     risingInt     low
885      BP08_vB         pause    high
868      BP08_vB    fallingInt     low
572      BP06_vB      duration    high
654      BP06_vB    fallingInt     low
67       BP01_vA    fallingInt     low
83       BP01_vA     risingInt    high
456      BP05_vA      duration     low
753      BP07_vB pauseDuration     low
437      BP04_vA pauseDuration    high
686      BP07_vB      duration    high
70       BP01_vA     risingInt     low
75       BP01_vA       pauseN2    high
1098     BP10_vA      duration     low
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your `data` dataset?  Also, are you sure your groups are in the correct order?  I would have guessed `participant` would be listed last in `group_by`.

Comment: If `participant` goes last, then the plots are way off. I'll post some data above (updated question).

Comment: Right, but what I meant is this: the error bar plot aggregating across participants in `dplyr` should be centred where the overall mean % is in the `xtabs`. Isn't that the case? Thanks for the info on 0-length groups too.

Comment: No, the mean of proportions will only equate the overall proportions of the denominators in each group is the same.  Look at `(0 + 1 + 1 + 1)/(1 + 1 + 1 + 2)` vs  `mean(c(0, 1, 1, .5))`.